# Repository bean defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Application, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a multi maven project

on the **ACCOUNTS**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.myproject*" })
@EntityScan("com.myproject*")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.myproject*")
public class MyProjectAccountsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyProjectAccountsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have a CustomerIndividual Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_individual")
public class CustomerIndividual {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fk_nationality", nullable = false)
    private Integer fkNationality;

    @Column(name = "fk_residence", nullable = false)
    private Long fkResidence;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sex_type", nullable = false)
    private SexType sexType;

    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_customer")
    @MapsId
    private Customer customer;
    
}
```

that has a ManyToOne relationship with an entity (SexType) into another module called **TYPES**.

So **ACCOUNTS** module has **TYPES** as a dependency.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.myproject*" })
@EntityScan("com.myproject*")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.myproject*")
public class MyProjectTypesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyProjectTypesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

SexType:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "sex_type")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id_sex_type", nullable = false))
public class SexType extends TypeEntity {

}
```

**ACCOUNTS** application failed to starts due to given exception:

> The bean 'accountRepository', defined in
> com.myproject.accounts.account.repository.AccountRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MyProjectAccountsApplication, could
> not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in
> com.myproject.accounts.account.repository.AccountRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MyProjectTypesApplication and
> overriding is disabled.

A solution for that is to create a separate Maven module for the application types with the controller and put the **TYPES** module as a dependency.

But I'm wondering if there is a better solution to avoid creating a new maven module.

Comment: another solution would be to simply change the name

Comment: @Stultuske change the name of what? There is only one AccountRepository class and is part of the ACCOUNTS module. The issue is that it is scanned through EnableJpaRepositories by both applications.

Comment: idd I missed that. Why do you have two applications there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple Spring Boot applications in one Maven project you need something to distinguish between them. One possible solution is to use different Spring profiles and activate only one per application.

Add @Profile annotation to the configuration class like this:

```
@Profile("types")
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyProjectTypesApplication {
// ...
}

@Profile("accounts")
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyProjectAccountsApplication {
// ...
}
```

You can then activate specific profile by setting JVM system parameter when running application:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=types/accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different paths for the project (com.myproject.accounts.account).
And then try @EnableJpaRepositories("com.set.new.path*")